# Elixir 1.4.2 installed, but elixir -v shows 1.3.2. Can't make a new project with Phoenix 1.3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to run `mix phx.new <project_name>` in my terminal to start a new phoenix 1.3 project, but I get the error message:

```
** (Mix) Phoenix v1.3.0-rc.1 requires at least Elixir v1.4.
You have 1.3.2. Please update accordingly
```

I ran `brew install elixir` before to get the new version, tried it again and get:

```
Warning: elixir-1.4.2 already installed
```

However I run `elixir -v` it tells me:

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.3.2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated here to help me get running.

Comment: `brew update && brew reinstall elixir`  ?

Comment: @Sheharyar I tried running that and get:

`==> Reinstalling elixir `

 `==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/elixir-1.4.2.sierra.bottle.`

`Already downloaded: /Users/Me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/elixir-1.4.2.sierra.bottle.tar.gz`

`==> Pouring elixir-1.4.2.sierra.bottle.tar.gz`

`  /usr/local/Cellar/elixir/1.4.2: 388 files, 5.5MB`

But when I run `elixir -v`, I still get it only showing 1.3.2 again. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: What's the output of `which elixir` ?

Comment: @Sheharyar `which elixir` yields `/opt/local/bin/elixir`

Comment: try `readlink \`which elixir\``

Comment: That command shows: `../lib/elixir/bin/elixir`

Comment: Have you tried checking the elixir version in a new terminal?

Comment: I tried just now and it still shows I only have `Elixir 1.3.2` I've also tried to uninstall and reinstall from a new terminal window with `brew remove elixir --force`, but same results when I check the version. Really appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: Are you using `kiex` or some other elixir version manager by any chance?

Comment: I do not believe I am. Running the `kiex` command in terminal shows `command not found` don't think I've downloaded anything else other than Elixir and Phoenix in the past.

Comment: [Let's continue this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138682/elixir-update-issues-on-osx)

Comment: @Sheharyar I see the discussion in chat, but can't reply because I don't have 20 reputation yet. But I tried uninstalling erlang and elixir, checked `elixir -v` which still shows 1.3.2 and `which elixir` still shows `/opt/local/bin/elixir` Really sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: That means you have another version of elixir installed on your system. You can use `readlink` to find it's path, remove it and then install the latest version using `brew`

Comment: @Sheharyar thank you!! As you can tell I'm still very new to getting the environment details down. I was able to track the problem thanks to your help. `elixir -v` is now 1.4.2 and `mix phx.new <project_name>` is now working. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

This might be happening because `phoenix-1.3` is installed with older version of `elixir`.

Please consider using [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) version manager for `elixir`.

Once it's installed, just add the `elixir` plugin.
After that you can set the version with `asdf global <name> <version>` command.
e.g. `asdf global elixir 1.4.2` and you're done.

It just manages a simple `.tool-versions` file to manage the version.

In our experience it has worked in almost every scenario, while we had faced problems with `homebrew` and `kiex`. Also, it works on `Linux`, `Docker`, `Windows` and `Mac` so it's safe to use it in order to reduce deployment time hiccups.

If you want to do it with `homebrew`, first run `where elixir` and then set the $PATH variable in your `.bash_profile` or `.zsh_profile` files accordingly.

After `elixir` is setup correctly, please install latest version of `phoenix` (as of this writing it's 1.3, and you may need to install it from archives).
But I guess you already have figured that out :)

Please let us know if you still face any problem.